# Update indefinite amount of chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there any way to update an indefinite amount of chart in Chartjs.

I tried to store each chart in a big array like that:

```
let allCharts = [];

let graph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: historyArray,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: moduleName,
          data: historyArray,
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        x: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
  });

allCharts.push(graph)
```

But as soon as I want to update the chart like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < allCharts.length; i++) {
   allChart[i].update()
}
```

It returns that update is not a method.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: maybe is a stupid question, but are you sure that Chart class instance have update method? you can check it by debug this code before the push instruction

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Not dumb to ask though gotta make sure I'm not dumb lmao ;) See the docs of it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: The code inside the `for` has a typo - `allChart` instead of `allCharts`; if that's not in the actual code, you have to investigate what exactly is `allCharts[i]`, use a `console.log` or a debugger. Also the good practice is to *quote* the full error, not *describe* it.

Comment: Exists a object where all charts are stored and available. Accessible by Chart.instances is an object where the key is the chart id, and the value is the chart itself